# Formula to compare the source and the target based on ID

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Source:

```
ID      Entity  Name            Trade Date      Side
88k     BC      66.00           18-Aug-09       S
1391    BED     89.00           18-Aug-09       P
74890   BED     74.00           18-Aug-09       P
74891   BED     ABCD0036        18-Aug-09       S
74892   BED     ADFGH0004       18-Aug-09       S
74893   BED     XFGT0057        18-Aug-09       P
74894   BED     CVBFGR0058      18-Aug-09       P
74895   BED     VVBRTG0041      19-Aug-09       P
74896   BED     FGFGFHC01       19-Aug-09       P
74897   BED     GHGHTGH0183     19-Aug-09       P
```

Target:

```
ID      Entity  Name            Trade Date  Side
88k     BC      66.11           18-Aug-09   S
74894   BED     CVBFGR0058      18-Aug-09   P
74897   BED     GHGHTGH0183     19-Aug-09   P
1391    BED     89.00           18-Aug-09   P
74890   BED     74.00           18-Aug-09   P
74895   BED     VVBRTG0041      19-Aug-09   P
74896   BED     FGFGFHC01       19-Aug-09   P
74891   BED     ABCD0036        18-Aug-09   S
74892   BED     ADFGH0004       18-Aug-09   S
7489222 BED     ADFG            18-Aug-09   S
```

1. If ID from the source matches with the target then need to check whether the corresponding columns are same.
2. If Records under the name is a number then the number needs to be converted to an integer and then compare.

I used the below formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,$A$15:$A$24,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$15:$A$24=$A2)*(IF(ISNUMBER(B2),INT(B$15:B$24)=INT(B2),B$15:B$24=B2)),0),0)),"")
```

It is not working. How can I make it work?

Comment: `ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$15:$A$24=$A2)*` do you really want to multiply a boolean with something else?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what I am guessing you want to is outlined below:

[image]